# How to get the files which is posted previous month

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I need to get the files which is posted in previous month, Along with the file path,file name and file size should be write on new file. Below is the script that I wrote. But its giving me the directory size and directory name.

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=`date +'%d%m%Y'`
YEAR=`date +'%Y'`
Temp_Path=/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/New_Vendors/
SFTP_PATH=/bishare/DLSFTP/DLSTREAM/
cd $SFTP_PATH
du -k --max-depth=1 >$Temp_Path/SFTP_VENDOR_FOLDER_SIZE_$CURRENT_DATE.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *find* command to achieve that:

```
find . -type f -newermt $(date +"%Y-%m-01" --date='-1 month') ! -newermt $(date +"%Y-%m-01") -exec du -sh {} \;
```

First condition is that the file modification timestamp is newer than a month ago, and the second condition is that the file modification stamp is not newer than this month. Basically you get everything in-between last month and this month.